# VBA in excel How to Save http://blahblah.pdf webpage as pdf file?

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, save

Currently my macro navigates through IE following specific links and brings me to a point where I click the pdf link and open it in IE.

What I am trying to do now is save that open page as a pdf file. I have tried URLDownloadtofile which saves the file but will not allow me to open it.

Here is a sample of the end of my code:

```
Loop
For Each e In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
If e.InnerText = "View Assigned Workout" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

For Each e In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("strong")
If e.InnerText = "View/Print Workout" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next

Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop
For Each e In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("strong")
If e.InnerText = "View Workout Card" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4)
DoEvents
Loop

For Each e In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("strong")
If e.InnerText = "Print" Then
e.ParentElement.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

At this point click the print link opens a file in IE
http://blahblah.pdf (cant access actual link as need login)

How do I save this file as a PDF to a folder on my desktop?

I tried using the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As     Long

Sub Test()
Dim strPDFLink As String
Dim strPDFFile As String
Dim Result As Boolean
strPDFLink =  "http://blahblah.pdf"
strPDFFile = "savetestworkout.pdf"
Result = DownloadFile(strPDFLink, strPDFFile)
End Sub

Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
Dim lngRetVal As Long
lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function
```

The file is created but when I try to open it an error occurs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Someone Please help on this